# ClassNotFound: UpdateableState in spring-data-neo4j-rest 3.3.0

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

The example application SampleMovieApplication https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/developer-resources/tree/gh-pages/language-guides/java/spring-data-neo4j runs without problems with the version 3.2.0.RELEASE of spring-data-neo4j-rest, but it gets an ClassNotFound exception with 3.3.0.RELEASE. The class org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.UpdateableState is missing. Does anybody know what happens to this class, and how this error can be avoided?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a incorrect dependency issue beween SDN-rest 3.3.0 and SDN 3.2.2.

If I also add a SDN-3.3.0 dependency to the pom it works. Thanks a lot for the heads up.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>movies-spring-data</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Movies-Example</name>


    <!-- tag::dependencies[] -->
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <start-class>movies.spring.data.neo4j.SampleMovieApplication</start-class>
        <spring-data-rest.version>2.3.0.RELEASE</spring-data-rest.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j-rest</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- end::dependencies[] -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Comment: This configuratuin gets me another ClassNotFoundException. This time it is org.springframework.data.mapping.PersistentPropertyAccessor. It is the Neo4JMappingContext that is trying to load the Accessor. org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jMappingContext.createPersistentEntity(Neo4jMappingContext.java:58). If I look into my Maven dependencies I see that org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons is used in the version 1.9.2.RELEASE. And this version does not contain the missing Accessor class.

Comment: Not sure where the wrong dependency comes from, the correct one is : <springdata.commons>1.10.0.RELEASE</springdata.commons>